# Import File Names into Word Table Column 1 - 1 Filename Per Row

Tags: vba, file, ms-word

I am trying to import file names into a word table. There are many scripts for importing files into Excel, but nothing for a word table :(

I will browse for the folder > Then import the filenames into Column 1

**1 filename per table row**

I am stuck on how to import or insert  the file names into the table.

```
Sub ImportFileName()
    Dim getFolder As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim aTable As Table
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    getFolder = getFolder
    If getFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    myFile = Dir(getFolder & "\" & "*.doc*", vbNormal)
    Set aTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    While myFile <> ""
        Set myDoc = Documents.Open(getFolder & "\" & myFile)
        'How do I import the file name into table column 1
        aTable.Rows.Add
        myDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
        myFile = Dir()
        Set myDoc = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

How can I import the filenames into the word table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the filename already. It is in `myFile`.

After `aTable.Rows.Add` the cursor is in the first cell of the new row. Just insert it with `Selection.InsertAfter myFile`.

EDIT:

The following sub in Word inserts a new 3-column table and lists all filenames.

```
Sub ListFilenames()
Dim myFile As String, getFolder As String

    getFolder = "<set your folder here>"
    myFile = Dir(getFolder & "\" & "*.doc*", vbNormal)

    ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3

    While myFile <> ""
        Selection.InsertAfter (myFile): Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
        Selection.InsertAfter ("Col2"): Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
        Selection.InsertAfter ("Col3"): Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell    ' this inserts a new row
        myFile = Dir()
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: HI Paul, my apologies - I am trying to insert 1 filename per row. I will edit question. I also tried selection.Insertafter - nothing happened :(

Comment: Thank you very much Paul, it did the job :)